# Weird appearance of $$state

Tags: angularjs, get

I would want to get a data from server using http.get with this kind of format.

```
{"username":"my name is"}
```

after retrieving the data, I plan to save the value of user in a variable. Using firebug, i go to network tab and check if I get the expected output, and it was correct. But weirdly, it couldn't display the value using this `{{}}`. and When I checked the value of my variable using `angular.element($0).scope()` what I get is something like this

[image]

```
//controller
$scope.userDetails={};
$scope.userDetails.userName = MyService.getUserName( );
console.log($scope.userDetails.userName );



 //service
    getUserName: function( ) {
        var response = $q.defer( );

        $http.get( ENV.apiEndpoint + '/getUsername' ).success( function( data ) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(typeof data);
            console.log( data);
            response.resolve( data[0].user.trim());
        })
        .error(function( data ) {
            console.log("reject");
            console.log(typeof data);
            console.log( data);
            response.reject( data);
        }) ;

        return response.promise;
    }
```

Why do I get that weird $$state object? and how can I get rid of it and get only the username